# IntelliJ Idea opens main, context menus and autocomplete on main display only

Tags: ubuntu, intellij-idea, multiple-monitors

I have used IntelliJ Idea (build 111.277) on a dual-monitor system with Ubuntu 11.04. Some popup UI elements, such as main menus, autocomplete lists opens on the primary (notebook) display only, when the main window take place on the secondary display.

Screenshot:

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix it?

UPDATE: System details

- JDK Java\Oracle 1.6.0.26
- Ubuntu 11.04 with Unity

IDEA starts on the secondary display. Secondary display is Samsung E2020 connected to the HP ProBook 6450b laptop, resolutions of both displays are the same.

Comment: What window manager do you use? What is the JDK vendor/version? Any specifics about your multi-display configuration? Does it happen if you start IDEA on the second display?

Comment: JDK Java\Oracle 1.6.0.26. Ubuntu 11.04 with Unity. IDEA starts on the secondary display. Secondary display is Samsung E2020 connected to the HP ProBook 6450b laptop, resolutions of both displays are the same.

Comment: I found [similiar bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-65507?projectKey=IDEA&query=dual+screen) in the JetBrains bug tracker which is marked as fixed. But I'm using last available version now (111.277) and it's still reproducable.

Comment: Your issue is different as it's specific to your Linux configuration. I don't recall similar reports recently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment IDEA is unable to properly handle such a configuration (due to [this bug](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-86392)). The workaround is to configure your X in Xinerama mode.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have a solution for this problem as it appears to be a new issue specific to this particular configuration. Please [file a bug to YouTrack](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA) with all the details.

Comment: Thanks for care. I'll create issue ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in JDK1.7, as it works if you downgrade to JDK 1.6.

Comment: As I describe in the [issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-80900), I'm launch Idea using JDK Java\Oracle 1.6.0.26